# Can I automaticly CC emails to an email address in Mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, email

Are there any email clients for Mac OSX (10.6.7) which can automaticly CC an email ID (without writing the CC email field)?

---

**Update 1** - I want to give an email ID to all the team members. I am using a shared hosting for my site where I am going to create all the email ID's. I will configure these ID's in default Mail.app. Now whenever my team send emails to clients I want it to CC to my email ID automatically.

Comment: Interesting, Apple mail will allow you to CC yourself but not another account.

Comment: Without writing in the cc mail field, are you revering to not having to type it?

Comment: Actually i want this for my team.. I want whatever mail they send it cc to me

Comment: Can you please be more specific in what you actually want to do (what addresses the emails will be sent to, what domain they will be using, if any groups involved, what kind of email clients the team will be using, etc.)? This can likely be done by assigning a rule and using a carefully crafted Applescript.

Comment: @cksum - please see my updated question.

Comment: There's still one important question you have not answers: What client will your team be using? If they are all using Apple's Mail.app, then this is doable. But if they are all using different clients (such as Microsoft Outlook or Thunderbird), then it's still likely doable, but you will have to find solutions for each client. Are they all going to be using OS X and the same email client?

Comment: @cksum - Well email client is not a preference here.. we can use any client which support this ... I am open to use Mail.app or thunderbird or any other client...We'll all use same client on all the computers

Answer (score 1):

If you switch your team over to Google apps, the Gmail web client lets you automatically cc or bcc every email, this is how I automated emails.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [MailActOn](http://indev.ca/MailActOn.html). It allows you to define rules for outgoing mails (among other things), one of the possible action is forwarding to a user-defined address.

Comment: do you know any free solution.. MailActOn is not free..